# Convert excel data(some cell contains pictures) to PowerPoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'd like to export a excel list data to power point slides, each line with 5 rows of data, one row is picture on it. Is there anyway to do it with VBA? Or if mailing merge able to do it? (By convert to word text lines them import to ppt). Can each row in the slide import to individual section (maybe textbox?). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, there are ways of doing this with VBA or other programming languages? But this isn't a code writing service. You'll need to write the code yourself (and ask for help with it here if you need it; people here are generous with help and knowledge).  There are also commercially available add-ins or other programs that can do this sort of thing for you.

Comment: Understand. Thanks.